# How to change p:barChart yaxis-tick color

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

How can I change the barChart yaxis-tick color

```
.jqplot-axis .jqplot-yaxis .jqplot-yaxis-tick{
     color: green;
}
```

I try any option that I could find (also using Firebug) and nothing is working

Any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the following `extender` function on your `barChart`:

```
function ext() {
    this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
        textColor : '#00ff00'
    };
}
```