# How to configure seriesDefaults in primefaces jqchart ?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jqplot

I have used jqplot in the past an dnow I am using it via Primefaces however I cannot seem to find the interface that will populate seriesDefaults. Does any one know how to do it as I need to set the fillToZero property otherwise the bar chart will not display negative values properly.

I had a look at the BaseChartRenderer and do not see that option coded, Could this be somewehere else ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the trick with extender function worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute called `extender` of every chart (jqplot) widget:

```
<p:barChart ... extender="extFn"/>
```

By introducing such function your gain access to the `cfg` object of the jqplot chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function extFn() {
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
            ....
        };
    }
```

Some SO answers showing the usage of extender functions:

- [Displaying decimal places on primefaces pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13092086/407466)
- [How to change p:barChart yaxis-tick color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13152899/407466)